# MTurk submit externalForm submit error

Tags: javascript, post, mechanicalturk

I have a node js app that generates the following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function post_form() {
            completedTask()
            var form = document.getElementById('myForm')
            form.submit()
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body class="bodygrad">
<div id="page" class="pageContainer">
    <form id="myForm" action="https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit" method="post">
        <input id="assignmentId" type="hidden" value="#{assignmentIdVar}">

        <div id="mainbody"> the assignmentId is #{assignmentIdVar} </div>
        <input id="confirmInput" type="submit" value="Next" onclick="post_form()">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am embedding this inside amazon mechanical turk using the ExternalQuestion. The documentation says

> The form must include the assignmentId field that was appended to the
>   URL used to access your form. It should be submitted along with the
>   other form fields submitted by your form, with a name of assignmentId
>   and the same value as was passed to the form.

In my html you can see i have an `input` field with id `assignmentId`, the value is set dynamically. I know the assignmentId is set correctly because I can see it in the `mainbody` div.

Now before submitting the form I want to run some javascript code, which I call inside the `completeTask()` and then submit the form. After `completedTask()` i submit the form using `form.submit()`, but this does not seem to be working - I get:

> There was a problem submitting your results for this HIT.
>
> This HIT is still assigned to you. To try this HIT again, click "HITs
>   Assigned To You" in the navigation bar, then click "Continue work on
>   this HIT" for the HIT. If this problem persists, you can contact the
>   Requester for this HIT using the "Contact" link above.
>
> To return this HIT and continue working on other HITs, click the
>   "Return HIT" button.

What am I doing wrong? How can I check what are the parameters associated with my post form?

Comment: Typically there are a few potential sources of error: (1) submitting to the sandbox submit URL instead of the live server, (2) using an incorrect, misspelled parameter label, or no value for `assignmentId`, (3) failing to submit at least one other field (e.g., `foo=bar`) along with the assignmentId.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas! I missed the extra field adding foo=bar!